# Content-MD5 for AWS S3 Signed UploadPart Header

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, alamofire

When using AWS MultipartUpload to upload parts, it fails if I add the md5 header. Can anyone tell if I'm calculating the checksum correctly?

Right now I'm just using `CryptoSwift` and grabbing it this way

```swift
data.md5().base64EncodedString()
```

Where data is what I'm uploading with

```swift
Alamofire.upload(
  data, 
  to: presignedMultipartLink, 
  method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod.put, 
  headers: [
    "Content-Length": sizeOfPart, 
    "Content-MD5": data.md5().base64EncodedString()
  ])
  .uploadProgress{...}
  .response{...}
```

And if I take out the Content-MD5 header it works as desired.

The xml response is, so how do I add the md5 header?

```xml
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message><HeadersNotSigned>content-md5</HeadersNotSigned><RequestId>requestid</RequestId><HostId>hostid</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: What is the error message from the XML in HTTP response, on the failed request?

Comment: ok here's the response <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message><HeadersNotSigned>content-md5</HeadersNotSigned><RequestId>requestid</RequestId><HostId>hostidhast</HostId></Error> (i've also added above)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot does that help? Any ideas?

Comment: is it that i have to actually generate all presigned urls with each md5 hash?

Comment: Yep, that's it.  `Content-MD5` and its value must be known at signing time, if it's included in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include in the getPresignedUrl call as a param. Cannot be included otherwise. Bah... one of those days.